# how to set the OffscreenPageLimit value to zero in android

Tags: android

I am using page adapter to implement horizontal swiping.I want to set OffscreenPageLimit to zero because i want that only the view which is on the screen is loaded only.But unfortunately its not working.Can anyone give me the alternate solution to that.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a `FragmentPageAdapter` it shouldn't be very tricky to accomplish what you're after. You just need to make sure that you don't any 'loading'* whenever the fragment gets created (or its parent activity, or attached etc). Rather create a method in the fragment that you can call to start the loading process. After that, set up an [`OnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) for the `ViewPager` and call that 'startLoad' method in either `onPageScrolled(...)` or `onPageSelected(...)` - whichever suits your needs better.

That way you still have more than one item in your adapter, but you initialise any offscreen pages with a very simply layout. Only when the page is scrolled you can start the hard work.

*= Note that 'loading' is kind of a vague term here. Having an adapter with just a single page doesn't really make any sense (as @fliespl already pointed out). In stead, as explained above, allow multiple pages and initialise anything not visible to some very basic state. Simply start the actual loading of content when a horizontal scroll reveals (part of) the page.

Just a tip: setting up an interface that defines the 'startLoad' method probably wouldn't be a bad idea. If you set it up correctly, you should be able to safely cast any items in the adapter and start the load, without having to worry about the actual implementation.

Comment: I think you are correct,Now i will implement the page listener.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you take a closer look, your logcat will output this string:
`Requested offscreen page limit 0 too small; defaulting to 1`, meaning you can't do it this way :)

If you don't want adapter, why do you use it? You can simply inflate and replace your layout or start new activites.